# Counterintuitive LeetCode Runtime difference in slight variable name changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime

I am very new to Leetcode, but I know a bit of programming. I thought I knew about what makes runtime slower or faster, but this Leetcode question is making me question everything. Below are 3 slightly different correct answers to the same easy question with the only difference being the name of the variables. I was under the assumption that shorter names would lead to faster runtimes, but not to this level of difference. All answers are the same space complexity. Can somebody explain why there's such a large difference despite the exact same logic?

This is the question:
Given an array of integers nums, calculate the pivot index of this array.

The pivot index is the index where the sum of all the numbers strictly to the left of the index is equal to the sum of all the numbers strictly to the index's right.

If the index is on the left edge of the array, then the left sum is 0 because there are no elements to the left. This also applies to the right edge of the array.

Return the leftmost pivot index. If no such index exists, return -1.

```
class Solution(object):
    def pivotIndex(self, nums):
left & right respectively...
        leftSum, rightSum = 0, sum(nums)
        # Traverse elements through the loop...
        for idx, ele in enumerate(nums):
            rightSum -= ele
            if leftSum == rightSum:
                return idx      
            leftSum += ele
        return -1      
#Runtime: 103ms and beats 95.77% of all submissions despite being the same with just different variable names
```

```
# Space Complexity : O(1)
class Solution(object):
    def pivotIndex(self, nums):
        lS, rS = 0, sum(nums)
        # Traverse elements through the loop...
        for i, e in enumerate(nums):
            rS -= e
            if lS == rS:
                return i      
            lS += e
        return -1
```

Runtime: 106ms and somehow beats 90.78% of all submissions despite it being identical to the first, just different names

```
class Solution(object):
    def pivotIndex(self, nums):
        leftS, rightS = 0, sum(nums)
        for index, count in enumerate(nums):
            rightS -= count
            if leftS ==rightS:
                return index
            leftS += count
        return -1
```

Runtime: 118ms and only beats 52.74% of the other submissions despite identical code, just different names

Comment: How often did you submit each, in what order, and what were the individual times? What is the baseline, i.e., what times do you get for submitting a solution that cheats by returning the answers from a hardcoded list of all the answers?

Comment: Where's the link to the problem?

Comment: 106 vs 118 is basically not different ... it takes more time to allocate more characters(maybe?)... or just noise in the system (maybe?) ... it is stupid to quibble over such small and insignificant gains

Comment: Once, submitted in reverse order. The runtimes are written in the question. None are hardcoded. The fastest one is a copy and paste from the most popular answer, the slowest was my answer and the mid was just me trying to make sense what's so different.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/find-pivot-index/?envType=study-plan&id=level-1

Comment: The difference is not great, but it just doesn't make sense. You'd think that more characters slow it down, but the one with the longest characters is the fastest.

Comment: Submitted each only once? Well... that's very bad. Do it multiple times, preferably alternating between them.

Comment: I found out the difference and most people don't care about it. The character size of the variable being looped (index, idx, i, e, count, ele) alters the runtime more than the character size of all other variables. It's insignificant relative to complexity, but nice to know in the face of data science.

Comment: That's not true. But feel free to show why you think that.

Comment: I submitted it a dozen times with the only difference being the character length. It showed a direct positive correlation between runtime and the length of that variable. To what extent, I'm not sure, but it seems pretty conclusive that is what is slowing the runtime.

Comment: And I still don't see any of those times.

Comment: How do I show you? You can just run it yourself. Unless all dozen submissions just happen to get increased runtimes with increasing character length, it seems pretty concrete.

Comment: By putting them into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the run times on LeetCode platform can change depending on load on specific LeetCode server where our code is getting executed at that point in time.

I think It is important to focus on the algorithmic complexity (the time and space complexity) of your solutions rather than the specific runtimes reported by LeetCode. The runtimes can be affected by factors beyond our control, but the algorithmic complexity is a more reliable measure of the performance of your code. In this case, all three solutions have the same time complexity (O(n)) and space complexity (O(1)), which is a more meaningful metric to compare them.

Comment: Microoptimizations with constant factor improvements can still be interesting and worthwhile. And if you notice an unexpected or even counterintuitive speed difference, I'd say it's good to look into it. With your argument, focus on big-O complexity, you'd also disregard it if one solution were ten times faster than another, which can have a real impact. Although in this case, I think there is ***no*** difference in speed of their three solutions, it's entirely due to outside factors.

Comment: After playing around with it and multiple submissions, I found out there is a difference that most people don't care about. The character size of the variable getting looped(index, idx, i, ele, count, e) is a larger determining factor than all other variable sizes. It doesn't matter in the large picture, but it's nice to know.